# Errors while building ns-3 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, build-error, ns-3

I am trying to install ns-3 but when I try to build with following command

sudo ./build.py

i am getting following errors:[image]

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you don't have enough memory space! if you work with VM, try to add more space

Answer (score 0):

following space is sufficient for installation?[image]